# Ubuntu 16.10 failed to startup after login

Tags: wine

1 hour ago ubuntu 16.10 successfully install to my computer without error but after wine was installed and trying to play NBA 2k14, only black screen displayed to my screen monitor so after 5 minutes I decided to restart my computer using the power button.

on startup after the login form, there was an error appear says that

> "System program problem detected"

then only the loading screen appears... why ubuntu are to many bugs even I do a clean installation?

Comment: There are probably so many bugs because you installed a development version of Ubuntu, not set for release until late October.

Comment: so this ubuntu version is under developing? 

I am always switching from windows to ubuntu a year ago until now because some reason on windows but because of ubuntu are using always a console (Terminal) to install the apps and many bugs appears I decided to switch back to window and now again... hope they will fix up on October... thanks man...

Comment: If you want a stable version, just install 16.04. It'll be supported until 2021.

Comment: is that version less of bugs?

Comment: Yes, hence why it's called stable.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely to be a bug. A quick search at Launchpad showed me no related bug, so you would do good to the community by [reporting this bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Notice also that there has **never** been a test for NBA 2k14 submitted to Wine for **any** Ubuntu distribution. This means this might not work, regardless of the release you install, stable or not stable. See [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29140) a list of tests for this game in Wine. The only test available is for a Debian distribution (not Ubuntu). If your interest is in playing this videogame only, you can try installing that OS. See more information about it [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/). Although a rather old release (2013), it still has Long Term Support until 2018, so it should be fine as an OS too (although people argue is more "difficult" to use for beginners).